# Using Java to compute 11^-1 mod 26

Tags: java, modular

How would I go about this n Java?

```
double power = (Math.pow(11,-1)) % 26;
System.out.println(power);
```

Just returns `0.09090909090909091`. According to [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11%5E-1%20mod%2026)

Thanks!

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Btw, 11^-1 = 1/11 ~= 0.09. This modulo 26 should obviously still result in the same value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java is technically correct, the inverse of 11 mod 26 is (approximately) 0.09090909090909 because 0.09090909090909 * 11 is approximately 1, whether mod 26 or not.

However, what you're trying to find is an integer with the same property, 19, because 19*11 = 1 mod 26, and you can't do that with the same approach.

Fortunately, the standard library has you covered:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            new BigInteger("11").modInverse(new BigInteger("26")));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the problem, +1 for giving this solution! (damn, why can't I up-vote twice?)

Comment: +1 I agree with Barranka, you'd deserve a double upvote just to understand what's the question!

Comment: I was a CS TA once upon a time :P

Comment: @Barranka What Stefano said -- helping other students with their class assignments in courses you've taken before. You get a trillion weirdly phrased questions about modular arithmetic that way.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks! I was not familiar with the term :)

Answer (score 1):

Wolframalfa doesn't interpret your syntax as expected. Instead of writing

```
11^-1 mod 26
```

try

```
mod(11^-1, 26)
```

which will return the [same result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mod%2811%5E-1%2C%2026%29) as your Java snippet.